# Where to put rewards in IInAppBillingService method?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have this method for `IInAppBillingService`:

```
                if (sku.equals(inappid)) {
                    Bundle buyIntentBundle = mservice.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku, "inapp",
                            "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                    if (buyIntentBundle.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE") == 0) {
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                        startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(),
                                Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));

                        * long starsLong = Menu.sharedPref.getLong("stars", 0L);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Menu.sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putLong("stars", starsLong + stele);
                        editor.commit(); *
                    } 
                }
```

but even if the user will **cancel the payment**, the award will be stack in the **sharedPreferences**. Where I should put the part with STARS for the award can stack only if the user pay (in which method, or what condition should i put)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. it's  **onActivityResult** method from the Activity class. Here you can put the condition if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) and this is called only when the user pay for your item.